# Flask-User /user/sign-in view, where is it?

Tags: flask, flask-user

This is prolly a stupid question but I am experimenting with Flask-User.  I see the `venv/.../flask_user/user_manager__settings.py` file and see

```
USER_LOGIN_URL = '/user/sign-in' #:
```

I do not see a method for this though.  *Something* is rendering a view for the sign-in page but I am not seeing the connection.  What part am I missing?

**Edit**

What am I asking?  I have copied the flask-user templates from site-packages into my test.  I have slightly tweaked them.  However, when I click the default Signin link I get an untweaked login template.  I am wondering if something has a hardwired template path?  I am just not finding that url->view->template linkage.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do/ask? There's a few places you can look. [`init_app`](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/blob/5c652e6479036c3d33aa1626524e4e65bd3b961e/flask_user/user_manager.py#L125) sets the login view, and [`user_manager_views`](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/blob/5c652e6479036c3d33aa1626524e4e65bd3b961e/flask_user/user_manager__views.py#L363) contains a `login_view`.

Comment: Fair question: I'll edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are config options to change the templates, for example:

```
USER_LOGIN_TEMPLATE = 'your/path'`
```

Found here: https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_settings.html